# How can I add a new level to a multilevel ordered list on the same line as the parent item?

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to write a question paper in Cambridge O Level question format.

I saw this kind of list:

```
1. Main list Item 1

2. Main list Item 2  

  (a) Sub list item 1

  (b) Sub list item 2

  (c) (i)  Sub Sub list item 1
    
      (ii) Sub Sub list item 2
```

As shown here, imbedded list (c) and imbedded imbedded list (i) are on the same line, list (c) doesn't have any text in it.

I have searched the internet and the only solutions I've found require  inserting  a table.

Does anyone know a way to make a list behave this way in Google Sheets?

---

I have found that it can easily be done in Latex, however not in microsoft word or google doc.

Comment: I've never seen an ordered list displayed in this manner. Are you sure this is what is expected if you? Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include a sample to the style guide that requires that. This is not how ordered lists work.

Comment: In Cambridge Question papers this kind of listing is quite frequent. I don't know what software Cambridge uses but I was given this task from the school I am working now, and the only softwares I have are google document and microsoft office word. Although I am not sure if it is possible in Latex, but the school wants it in a doc or word file.

Comment: *"doc or word file"* I presume they *want* that for compatibility(?) but if you have to hack the format to get it to work that might defeat the goal anyway.